# Express $\operatorname{Log}(i-z)$ as a Taylor series centered at $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, taylor-expansion

How can I express $\operatorname{Log}(i-z)$ as a Taylor series centered at $z=1$ ???

---

I have tried to first derivate the function, for then integrating it. But I think that I'm doing it wrong... I'm having problems with the $i$

How can I do it?

---

*Edit:

With the suggestion given, I've done the following:$\space$

$Log(i-z)=Log((i-1)(1-(\frac{z-1}{i-1})))=Log(i-1)+Log(1-(\frac{z-1}{i-1}))$$\space$

We know that $\space$ $Log(i-1)=ln(\sqrt{2})+\frac{3\pi}{4}i$$\space$

And we also know that $\space$ $Log(1-(\frac{z-1}{i-1}))=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{z-1}{i-1})^{n+1}}{n+1}$

But now I don't know how to continue...

Comment: You derived $$
\log (i - z) = \log (i - 1) - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n(i - 1)^n }}(z - 1)^n } .
$$ Isn't this a Taylor series centered at $1$?

Comment: Oh that's true! Thanks! And now, how can I calculate the convergence radius? @Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: $$i - z = (i-1) - (z-1)= (i-1) \left( 1 -\left(z-1\over i-1 \right) \right).
$$

Comment: And what can I do with that???

Comment: Take the logs, use $\log (a \cdot b) = \log a + \log b $ (with appropriate care...) and then use the power series expansion of $\log (1 - x)$ which I assume you know (or know how to get).

Comment: I have continued with the exercise with the information you have given me; thanks! (I have made an edit to my post). But know I don't know how to continue... what can I do?

Comment: You don't feel you're done? You have an expansion of the form $\sum a_n (z-1)^n$ (where you can solve for $a_n=....)$. Unless you want to throw in the appropriate factorials to exhibit the derivatives at $z=1$? But otherwise...

Comment: And now how can I calculate the convergence radius?

Comment: ratio test, for instance.